# SQL SUM total using 2 tables

Tags: sql, sum

I have 2 tables: `TBL_EQUIPMENTS` and `TBL_PROPOSAL`.

`TBL_PROPOSAL` has 3 important columns:

- id_proposal
- date
- discount

`TBL_EQUIPMENTS` has:

- id_equipment
- id_proposal
- unit_price
- quantity

Now I want to know how much (in €) is my proposals for this year, let's say:

For each `TBL_PROPOSAL.date > "2013-01-01"` I want to use the formula:

```
result = (TBL_EQUIPMENTS.unit_price * TBL_EQUIPMENTS.quantity) * (100 - TBL_PROPOSAL.discount)
```

I can do this with one SQL statement?

Comment: your question is not clear... be specific.. which colum you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
select e.unit_price * e.quantity) * (100 - p.discount)
from tbl_Proposal p join
     tbl_Equipments e
     on p.id_Proposal = e.id_proposal
where date >= '2013-01-01'
```

The basic syntax is for a join.  The `p` and `e` are called table aliases.  They make the query easier to read (the full table names are rather bulky).

Date operations differ among databases.  The last statement should work in most databases.  However, you might try one of the following as well:

```
where year(date) = 2013
where extract(year from date) = 2013
```

Comment: thank you very much. You read my mind :)) The next tip if very usefull, because I want the user to select "This year" "This month" and you're tip comes in the right moment. Thank you once more.
With your help I can have a list of values and now I read all of them and make the SUM. Is there a way to have the sum of all rows? I've tried to change the code to
SELECT SUM(e.unit_price * e.quantity) * (100 - p.discount)
This SUM doesn't give me the correct value. Could you help me once more? Thank you